# Why doesn't stopPropagation stop bubbling of click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span tag inside an anchor tag. When span is clicked I want the link to not get followed, that is I want to stop the click on span to trigger(bubble up) click on anchor tag. For that I used stopPropagation as:

```js
$("a span").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
  hello <span> click here </span>
</a>
```

As you can see the click event is still propagated to anchor tag. Instead, if I use `e.preventDefault()` then that seems to stop the bubbling up. Why isn't the `stopPropagation` stopping the propagation of click event?

Comment: Because of the event flow. Review the following: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-capture

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Slico/u88u7tas/1/

Comment: @Slico think you're missing some parentheses after `isPropagationStopped`. It returns the function itself, rather than `true`.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Slico/u88u7tas/2/

Answer (score 4):

`e.preventDefault()` is what you want. What you're describing isn't a result of event propagation, it's a result of the default behaviour of a link which is what you're trying to prevent.

Consider the following example:

```js
$('a span').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();      
});

$('a').click(function(e) {
  alert('propagated!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
  hello <span> click here </span>
</a>
```

Had `e.stopPropagation()` not been called, the `click` handler for the anchor itself would be called and you'd get the `alert`.

Comment: Ooops just posted something just like yours... deleting it. However, your snippet still doesn't show the point, because it navigates away. If you add a onbeforeunload, the user can cancel the page from being unloaded and observe that the direct handler on A wasn't called.

Comment: So the actual browsers' implementation is to follow `href` of parent anchor tag. Do all browsers do the same? Is this behavior specified by w3c?

Comment: @JuanMendes, a fair point, but if `e.stopPropagation()` had not been called, the `alert` would block the navigation until it's dismissed.

Comment: That's true, probably a good idea to explain that in the answer